# Google Internal oAuth Consent Screen with multiple domains

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth

I have an internal oAuth consent screen working for the organisation domain `domain.com`.

We have add an additional users that have been added to the organisation with their domain `domain.ag` (.ag is where we are moving to, which is on a different account at the moment).

I can login and do what I need with the `.com` emails, but when using the `.ag` emails google is saying they are not part of the organisation.

Is there a way in 2021 to allow for this?

I have seen a questioned asked that is very similar to this where the answers where to add select_profiles to the query, or to make the app public.  Making the app public is not an option, and select_profiles is good, but if selecting the `.ag` email, I still get the same issue.

Is there a way to allow for all users under your organisation, even if they are 'shared' in via the Cloud Console IAM & Admin area?

Answer (score 2):

Since your application is purely internal and has users on multiple domains, whitelist this application by marking it trusted.  To mark the app as trusted is using this https://support.google.com/a/answer/7281227

Comment: thanks for replying.  I have done this (I found this a few days back), when login in with the .ag domain I do get the `Error 403: org_internal` error still.  I did the whitelist changes on .com domain end, not the .ag end, does it need to be done at the .ag end as well (I would assume no since it isn't where the gcp is)

Comment: Are the users with .ag domain under same G Suite account as the user with .com domain?  

The authorized domains in the OAuth consent screens are the list of domains from where the OAuth tokens can be requested, in other words the domains where you can host the application, not G Suite accounts that can use the application

Comment: no they are not, they have been setup separately for some unknown reason

Comment: Can you try moving them and login then?

Comment: eventually, this will be the case, but not for the close future
if it can't be done with separate organisations (even with the `.com` domain users added to the `.ag` gcp account), then for now I think that will have to do